# Reduce/remove plot margins in Shiny apps including wordclouds

Tags: r, shiny, word-cloud

If I replicate [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/word-cloud.html) of R Shiny app on my computer - [full code and data here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/082-word-cloud) - the image generated by Shiny has significant white margins that end up cutting some of the words.

Here is an example of the image generated:
[image: example wordcloud]

Notice that the white space is included in the actual png file generated by shiny, not from white space around the image. The example functions correctly when I see it [online from the rstudio servers](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/word-cloud.html).

Possible hint: if I increase the resolution (e.g. by setting `res = 150` in renderPlot), this white margin increases further. See output image:
[image: larger white margin]

How can I remove this white space completely?

Edit: by increasing canvas size (width and height in `plotOutput`), and keeping the same resolution in `renderPlot` (or by reducing the resolution there), you are less likely to encounter the problem. But the white margin is still there. I want to remove completely the white margin generated by the plot, as in my real life case I have more complex wordclouds, `comparison.cloud`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually managed to deal with it by adding `par(mar = rep(0, 4))` before each call to `wordcloud` in the server.R file. I don't know if this leads to potential other issues, but for the moment it seems to answer my own question (it removes the white margins from wordclouds in shiny).

Comment: The funny thing is that the [source code for wordcloud](https://github.com/cran/wordcloud/blob/master/R/cloud.R) includes such a call. Have you found a better fix?

Answer (score 4):

You can escape this problem by defining the plot size in pixels.

In the demo code this way:

```
# Show Word Cloud
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot",width = "500px", height="500px")
)
```

Comment: Not really. This makes the canvas larger, so it is less likely that you encounter the problem. But the problem (the white margin) is still there, as you'll see if you reduce the "minimum frequency" and increase the "maximum number of words" in the example app, or if you increase resolution with the res parameter. I want to actually remove the white margin that is created inside the png file.

Comment: @giocomai, you are absolutely right. I shared a hack to ease your pain. I, myself, look forward to a solution that solves the white-margin problem. :)

Comment: thanks! :-) indeed, setting e.g. "res = 50" in `renderPlot` also achieves similar results. Looking forward to a more definitive solution.